# Create folder for each file name and move the file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have batch file that needs to sort csv file based on the first few numbers of the csv file. The files are in one folder and after detecting the first few numbers before the underscore, it should assign and set them a name e.g

1. C:\FDM\FDMConversion\890_AMMC1_Recording_2012.csv
2. C:\FDM\FDMConversion\898000_AMMC1_Recording_2012.csv

Basically, I want the script to pick each file and create a folder.
for example, to move  890_AMMC1_Recording_2012.csv, the script will extract 890 and create a folder sample1 and then move the file into sample1. 
and to move 898000_AMMC1_Recording_2012.csv the script will extract 898000 and create a folder sample2 and move the file into sample2 folder

Code is below :

```
    set filename="C:\FDM\FDMConversion\*.csv"

for /f %%i in ('dir %filename% /b /a-d ') do (
    set "filename=%%~i"
    for /f "delims=_ tokens=1" %%a in ('echo !filename!') do (  

rem rem    set folder=%%a 

 If "%%a"=="890" ( 
set sample1=%%a
mkdir "C:\FDM\FDMConversion\!sample1!"   2>nul
for /f "delims=_ tokens=1" %%a in ('echo !filename!') do set ade=%%a

 pushd "C:\FDM\FDMConversion"
for /r %%a in ("\!ade!*.csv" ) do (
   move /Y "%%a" "C:\FDM\FDMConversion\!ade!\%%~nxa"

   )
popd
)


If "%%a"=="898000" ( 
set sample2=%%a
mkdir "C:\FDM\FDMConversion\!sample2!"   2>nul
for /f "delims=_ tokens=1" %%a in ('echo !filename!') do set ade=%%a
 pushd "C:\FDM\FDMConversion"
for /r %%a in ("\!ade!*.csv" ) do (
   move /Y "%%a" "C:\FDM\FDMConversion\!ade!\%%~nxa"

   )
popD
)

)
```

Comment: `If "%%a"==898000 ( ` will never be true since one side of the operator is quoted and the other not. What do you mean by `sorted` since there is no sorting taking place? Please provide clear examples of expected start conditions and desired end conditions.

Comment: It is edited now

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed it. closing bracket and  remove the do set...

Comment: What do you mean by *"the script will extract 890"*? what do you do with 890?

Comment: It is already fixed. I meant that the script will select the first few letters before the underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    echo off 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION



set filename="C:\FDM\FDMConversion\*.csv"

for /f %%i in ('dir %filename% /b /a-d ') do (
    set "filename=%%~i"
    for /f "delims=_ tokens=1" %%a in ('echo !filename!') do (  

rem rem    set folder=%%a 

 If "%%a"=="890" ( 

mkdir "C:\FDM\FDMConversion\sample1"   2>nul
for /f "delims=_ tokens=1" %%a in ('echo !filename!') do set ade=%%a

 pushd "C:\FDM\FDMConversion"
for /r %%a in ("\!ade!*.csv" ) do (
   move /Y "%%a" "C:\FDM\FDMConversion\sample1\%%~nxa"

   )
popd
)


If "%%a"=="898000" ( 

mkdir "C:\FDM\FDMConversion\sample2"   2>nul
for /f "delims=_ tokens=1" %%a in ('echo !filename!') do set ade=%%a
 pushd "C:\FDM\FDMConversion"
for /r %%a in ("\!ade!*.csv" ) do (
   move /Y "%%a" "C:\FDM\FDMConversion\sample2\%%~nxa"

   )
popD

)


)




   )
```